# Michael Hartls RoR tutorial: scss is not targeting input

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, sass, railstutorial.org

I am writing with regards to a problem I am facing while working through Michael Hartl's tutorial for Ruby on Rails. The problem is that css does not change appearance of input field for password confirmation. All other input fields appearances are affected by the css rules. Please find pictures and files below:

[What I get:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YcWNf.png)

```css
// app/assest/stylesheets/custom.scss

@mixin box_sizing {
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

/* forms */

input, textarea, select, .uneditable-input {
  border: 1px solid #bbb;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  @include box_sizing;
}
```

```html
# app/views/users/new.html.erb

<% provide(:title, 'Sign up') %>
<h1>Sign up</h1>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
    <%= form_for(@user, url: signup_path) do |f| %>
      <%= render 'shared/error_messages' %>

      <%= f.label :name %>
      <%= f.text_field :name, class: 'form-control' %>

      <%= f.label :email %>
      <%= f.email_field :email, class: 'form-control' %>

      <%= f.label :password %>
      <%= f.password_field :password, class: 'form-control' %>

      <%= f.label :password_confirmation, "Confirmation" %>
      <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, class: 'form_control' %>

      <%= f.submit "Create my account", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
```

I've attempted to comment out line `@include box_sizing;` or give fixed height like `height: 25px;`, but it didn't help.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: your css actually works however appearance seems to be over written by form-control class delete it and see the effect

Comment: You need to show the generated CSS and HTML

Answer (score 1):

I can't tell you how many times this happened to me.

Check your spelling on your classes. Bootstrap commonly uses hyphens instead of underscores, and you've got a `form_control` class on your `:password_confirmation` field when it should be `form-control`

Comment: I have no idea why, but problem fixed on its own. Anyway, thank you for help!